# How to use min-conflict algorithm with optaplanner

Tags: optimization, optaplanner, rostering

Is there a min-conflict algorithm in optaplanner? or how to do it?

What about using it as part of the neighborhood selection like:

1. Define custom swap factory that construct neighborhood as follow
2. Get all violations per variable to optimize, thus requires a call to scoreDirector.calculateScore then parse/process constraintMatches
3. Order by variables lowest score or highest violations
4. Construct neighborhood via swapping those variables first

If that's viable, is there a way to get the constraintMatches without the need to re-call the calculateScore in order to speed up the process

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm isn't supported out of the box yet by OptaPlanner. I 'd call it **Guided Local Search**. But it's not that hard to add yourself. In fact, it's not a matter of changing the algorithm, but changing the entity selectors.

Something like this should work:

```
<swapMoveSelector>
  <entitySelector>
    <cacheType>STEP</cacheType>
    <probabilityWeightFactoryClass>...MyProbabilityWeightFactory</probabilityWeightFactoryClass>
  </entitySelector>
</swapMoveSelector>
```

Read about [the advanced swapMoveSelector configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#swapMoveSelector), [entity selector](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#entitySelector), [sorted selection](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#sortedSelection) and [probability selection](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#probabilisticSelection).

The callback class you implement for the probabilistic selection or sorted selection should prioritize entities that are part of a conflict.

I would definitely use sorted or probabilistic selection on the entity selector, not the entire swapMoveSelector because that is overkill, cpu hungry and memory hungry.

I would prefer probabilistic selection over sorted selection. Even though sorted selection better reflects your pseudo code, I believe (but haven't proven) that probabilistic selection will do better, given the nature of Metaheuristics. Try both, run some benchmarks with the Benchmarker and let us know what works best ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how to solve your overall problem but for your last point:

You can create a `PhaseLifecycleListener` and attach it via `((DefaultSolver) solver).addPhaseLifecycleListener`

In the stepStarted or stepEnded(depending on your need) you can then call

```
stepScope.getScoreDirector().getConstraintMatchTotals()
```

to get the constraint totals.

Hope this somewhat helps.

Comment: I afraid that would still need the `calculateScore()`  call to make sure the constraint matches are created.
It would indeed reuse the workingSolution's DroolsScoreDirector (instead of creating a new one), but he can't do much with it because it must not escape the solver thread: if it does, other threads will see it change surprisingly as the working solutions (including it's ConstraintMatches) changes during further solving.

Comment: I am sorry you are right, I did have to call calculateScore() in my code. Out of curiosity why can we not store the bestScoreConstraintMatchTotals in the solver scope the same way we store the best solution and best score? To avoid having to recalculate the score.

Comment: Good question. Feel free to [create a jira issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER) for that, so we can evaluate this feature request properly. Currently it doesn't do that because 1) constraint match tracking is enabled by default - which is 10% faster in some cases - but some algo's might need it in the future in which case it does get enabled and 2) they would need to be planning cloned when going from the working solution to the best solution. I recommend using a separate SolverDirector (see docs "Explaning the score") to get the constraint matches of a best solution.